# Bootstrap Tab Grouping

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am wondering if anyone has an example of grouping tabs together (Note i am not looking for nested tabs)

The below image is an example of what i am looking for:

[image: p]

Example Code from https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_menu_list-inline&stacked=h

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tabs</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> This example shows how to create a basic navigation tab. It is not toggleable/dynamic yet (you can't click on the links to display different content)- see the last example in the Bootstrap Tabs and Pills Tutorial to find out how this can be done.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My answer :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tabs</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home<br /> &nbsp;</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1<br /> &nbsp;</a></li>
    <li>
<div style="border:1px solid black;box-sizing: border-box;">
<div style ="text-align: center;">Group 1</div>
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div></li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> This example shows how to create a basic navigation tab. It is not toggleable/dynamic yet (you can't click on the links to display different content)- see the last example in the Bootstrap Tabs and Pills Tutorial to find out how this can be done.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what exactly you mean by grouping? Should change the style of the 2 links/tabs together?

Comment: @DhavalJardosh i have added my own solution to the question not sure how good it is but maybe someone can come up with a better one :)

Comment: @fox909a You can use the answer box instead.

Comment: @fox909a, your answer looks good to me. There is a CSS way of doing it but that's way more work than your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer i ended up using in the end was this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tabs</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home<br /> &nbsp;</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1<br /> &nbsp;</a></li>
    <li>
<div style="border:1px solid black;box-sizing: border-box;">
<div style ="text-align: center;">Group 1</div>
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div></li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> This example shows how to create a basic navigation tab. It is not toggleable/dynamic yet (you can't click on the links to display different content)- see the last example in the Bootstrap Tabs and Pills Tutorial to find out how this can be done.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank You for your help! :)